# Order statuses management crashes on local site

Tags: magento

Got a pretty strange issue here, maybe someone had similar experience. When loading http://magento.dev/index.php/cmd/sales_order_status/ locally it crashes with message

> Cannot retrieve entity config: sales/order_status_label

though on the same database (which is imported to the local server, I'm using MAMP Pro 2.0.1) but on the live store it works perfectly and opens the page

Could it be because of database or PHP differences? MySQL 5.5.9, PHP 5.2.17 on the local versus MySQL 5.1.56 PHP 5.3.6 on the live

I can attach a stack trace if needed

Comment: Magento administration and operations questions are not on-topic on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Question wasn't about administration, I mentioned server software because I thought it's a possible culprit. It turned out to be Magento configuration problem. That's why I've posted an answer if someone has similar misconfiguration problem in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due borked config.xml in core Sales module.

Generally such error means that the node in  section is missing or wrong for specified model and `getEntity` method in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource` returns an empty string